# What legal items should I know about if I am piggy-backing off of another bitcoin exchange?

Tags: exchanges, legal

I am thinking of starting a crypto exchange in the US, and I am piggybacking off of AlphaPoint's exchange for liquidity's sake.

What legal documents should I be aware of if I am piggy-backing? FinCEN comes to mind, and I may have to reject customers from NY :(

Thanks for the help in advance, I just want to get a scope on the extreme regulation before I start

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about regulation, you should be contacting a lawyer to help you remain compliant.